# Magento Catalog Product indexing error during Enterprise to Community downgrade

Tags: mysql, magento, indexing

We're attempting to downgrade from Magento EE 1.13 to CE 1.8.1.

We're working from a fresh CE codebase, but attempting to use the same database, which we understood should be doable from topics such as this one:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/how-to-migrate-from-enterprise-edition-to-community-edition

The site works well after removing any Enterprise references we find, but one bug we haven't been able to solve is an error on indexing:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magentodb`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DE)' in /mnt/hgfs/public/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Most of the results in searching for this error suggest trying to find a reference to a nonexistent product in the catalog_category_product tables, which makes sense given the foreign key constraint failing:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
category_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_category_entity);
```

But these queries return empty sets - there don't appear to be any references to entity_ids that don't exist in the entity tables.

Any suggestion on where this might be coming from?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to PhpMyAdmin and run this query:

   ALTER TABLE catalog_category_product_index DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID
2. Run Reindexing from Magento Admin Panel or from CLI;
3. After the reindexing is complete, run this query from PhpMyAdmin:

   DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product_index` WHERE 
   product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
   ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product_index` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Answer (score 0):

Reread that error.  Carefully

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(   `magentodb`.`catalog_category_product_index`, 
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 

    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) 
        REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DE)'
```

Specifically the part where they reference the table

```
`magentodb`.`catalog_category_product_index`,
```

The foreign key constraint is failing when the indexing code attempts to insert or update a column in `catalog_category_product_index`.  I'd check that this table is clean as well.

Answer (score 0):

exception 'PDOException' with message

```
'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magentodb`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DE)' in /mnt/hgfs/public/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

for this error i got solution. Check below information

Below is the process we used to solve the reindexing issue for Category Products (Indexed category/products association):

1. Log into phpMyAdmin
2. Go to `catalog_category_product_index`
3. Click “Export”.
4. Export only structure with “Disable foreign key checks” enabled.
5. Drop the table `catalog_category_product_index`
6. With the SQL that was exported, remove the constraints at the
   bottom of the export.  Be sure to keep the “SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS”
   statements.
7. Click “SQL”, paste in modified SQL and click “Go”
8. Login to Magento backend
9. Go to: System -> Index Management
10. Click “Reindex Data” next to “Category Products” index